# Multiple calculations of standard deviation on array subsets by index

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Say I have a numpy array: `my_array = np.random.rand(100)`.

and another array of indices: `ind_array = ([35, 58, 77])`

What would be the fastest way to calculate the standard deviation of the 10 values around each `ind_array` index in `my_array`? (i.e. `np.std(my_array[30:40]), np.std(my_array[53:63]), np.std(my_array[72:82])` )

It is obviously possible to do using a for-loop, but I'm afraid it will be too slow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** One approach leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) -

```
np.std(my_array[ind_array[:,None] + np.r_[-5:5]],axis=1)
```

**Approach #2 :** We can also leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for a more efficient solution -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

np.std(view_as_windows(my_array,(10))[ind_array-5],axis=1)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.